# Некорректно работает goodFeaturesToTrack в третьей версии OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

Пытаюсь найти особые точки кадра с помощью функции goodFeaturesToTrack в OpenCV 3.0:

```
Mat frame, gray_frame;
cap >> frame;
cvtColor(frame, gray_frame, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
vector<Point2f> keypoints;
int maxCorners = 500;
double qualityLevel = 0.01;
double minDistance = 10;
double blockSize = 3;
bool useHarrisDetector = false;
double k = 0.04;
goodFeaturesToTrack(gray_frame, keypoints, maxCorners, qualityLevel,    minDistance);
```

Почему вместо особых точек в keypoints записывается "мусор"? С версией 3.1 аналогичная история.

Answer (score 0):

Я использую `goodFeaturesToTrack` время от времени и знаю наверняка, что она работает и в 3.1, и в 3.0 работала. Возможно особые точки в Вашем понимании нечто иное, чем в понимании [уважаемых Shi & Tomasi?](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_shi_tomasi/py_shi_tomasi.html). Вероятно, указанный Вами MYCOP и есть особые точки для них? 
В коде всё правильно. Попробуйте еще Harris - может быть его понимание ближе к Вашему? :-)